# Apache does not load the correct file

Tags: php, html, apache, composer-php

**Enviroment**

```
Host - Windows 10
Browser - GoogleChrome (Caching is disabled )
IDE - Intelij IDEA

Oracle VirtualBox with CentOS 7
Apache Server
PHP Version 5.6.29
PHP Composer
```

**Problem**

I have a very frustrating behavior on my System.

If I start my VirtualBox and the Apache, the website is shown correkt, but if I change something in my HTML it is not load into the browser, but on the share folder it is correct.

[image: Screen from IDE IDEA]

[image: Code in the Shared folder]

[image: Loaded file from the browser]

But if I remove the button, it is shown correct ( without a button ). If I add the button again, on an other position, the button is shown at the old position with the old label.

Does someone can explain this behavior or has some knowhow about this behavior?
I have no idea which component trigger this behavior.

**------- UPDATE 1 ---------**

The `login.html` file is in `UTF8`.

One thing I have not seen before ist, this line at the editor (developer mode)  in the browser.

[image]

**----------- UPDATE 2 -----------**

*I add this update to create a better description of the problem.*

This is the `HTML` of the original.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="POST" action="../controller/login.php">
    <input id="txtUsername" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Output of the original HTML Code]

If I move the submit button to the top, or change the original code, and click on `CTRL` and `F5`, nothing change. Only in the browser developer editor appears the red dots ( if I hover over one dot, I get the tooltip  `\u0` )

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="POST" action="../controller/login.php">
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit"/>
    <input id="txtUsername" type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
</form>
```

[image]

The following slide shows, that on the server in the source folder the file has changed correct.

[image]

Comment: Maybe a cache problem? Try refresh page CTRL+F5

Comment: no, I have tried. If i change something in the `html` I can see, that something is changed, but the wrong thing. If I add a `<button..> ` I can see them.  If I move it 2 lines up... i've got 3 `text fields`, but no `button`. Now I try to work with a `<input type="submit">`, this works, but... why i can not use the button tag. on  http://caniuse.com/#search=button I can see, that the button tag should be able to use in my browser (Chrom  55.0.2883.87 m). .

Comment: Doesn't sound like a PHP issue.. What is the correct behavior, can you show the correct display and code as well? You also should add the actual code to the the question. Users dont want to transcribe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason of this problem is simple.
The CRLF in Windows is not the same like in CentOS, there it is a LF.

An other problem, which need a little time was, that the CRLF was not able to read in my IDE or an other tool which I use.

With the `dos2unix` I can fix it.